# Refreshing data output from database (PHP)

Tags: php, ajax

So, I have this code below which gets the data from my database, but I want this data to 'Refresh' Every 5 seconds so that when something new is put in the database which is matching the specifications shows up. (I don't want the page to refresh for this, only data...)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE reference = '1' ORDER BY datePosted asc LIMIT 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $title = $row["titel"];
      $description = $row["description"];
  }
} else {
    echo "Nothing found";
}
```

I've been looking for AJAX and PHP ways to do this, but I just don't seem to figure it out... Any help / info is appreciated!

Comment: Kind of threw my rubbish away.. But what I've tried is put this in a function and then call the function each 5 seconds in JQ, for some reason it didn't work.. @KoenHollander (Ik versta ook nl...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this;

```
<div id='contentToUpdate'></div>


<script type="text/javascript">


    setInterval(function(){
        LoadContent(); // this will run after every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);


    function LoadContent(){

        $.ajax({

            type:"POST",
            url: "/path/to/script.php",
            data: {GenerateContent: true, PostName2: 'value2'},

            success: function(result){

                $("#contentToUpdate").html(result);

            }, error: function(result){

                alert('something went wrong');

            }, complete: function(result){

                // fires regardless of above

            }

        });

    }

</script>
```

In the php file the receives the Ajax request you could have something like this;

```
    if(isset($_POST['GenerateContent'])){


        $aResults = array();

        $sql = "SELECT title, description FROM items WHERE reference = '1' ORDER BY datePosted asc LIMIT 5";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        while($row = $result->fetch()){
            $aResults[] = array('title' =>$row['title'], 'description' => $row['description']);
        }


        // if there are results output them
        if(!empty($aResults)){

            // foreach result
            foreach ($aResults as $iKey => $aResult) {
                echo "<p>";
                echo "Title: ".$aResult['title']."<br>\n";
                echo "Description: ".$aResult['description']."<br>\n";
                echo "</p>";
            }

        }else{
            echo 'No results have been loaded';
        }


        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Could you convert this into something that uses time to do this? Because this is something I can do too, the timing stuff is something I don't understand :) @atoms

Comment: @atoms Before I try this and tell you it doesn't work, are the value and value2 the names of my vars in php?

Comment: no they are javscript vars. Left it there to illustrate how you can post data to php.

Comment: just tested code and its working (updated). Just change the url path

Comment: It works, but It's not showing any data on my webpage yet.. How can I fix that? (I'm also getting the Something went wrong alert)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128445/discussion-between-coderyordi-and-atoms).

Comment: thats becuase the `/path/to/script.php` is incorrect. If you use a network inspector tool (Firefox has a great one), you'll see its causing a `404`.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and help! Really made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
setInterval(function()
{ 
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"path/to/script.php",
      success:function(data)
      {
          //do something with response data
      },
      error:function(e){
         console.log("Error Occurred");
      }
    });
}, 5000);//time in milliseconds 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can try something like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

function loadData(){
    $('#table').load('yourScript.php',function (response, status, xhr) {
         // handle the response here and set the data
    });
}

loadData(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadData(); // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```